# The command to create a file in docker via make does not work

Tags: windows, docker, makefile, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

Docker Toolbox is installed on a Windows 8.1 PC. When I enter the command in the PhpStorm terminal, it works successfully and the file is created:

```
docker run --rm -v //D_DRIVE/work/7_project-manager/manager:/app --workdir=/app alpine touch .ready
```

If I put the same command in the Makefile and run `make manager-ready`

```
manager-ready:
    docker run --rm -v //D_DRIVE/work/7_project-manager/manager:/app --workdir=/app alpine touch .ready
```

it works out with an error (other make commands work fine, the problem is only with this command):

```
D:\work\7_project-manager>make manager-ready
docker run --rm -v //D_DRIVE/work/7_project-manager/manager:/app --workdir=/app alpine touch .ready
C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: the working directory 'C:/msys64/app' is invalid, it needs to be an absolute path.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe run --help'.
make: *** [Makefile:43: manager-ready] Error 125
```

How to solve the problem?

Comment: Which terminal do you use?

Comment: Martin Tovmassian, Command Prompt in PHPStorm

Comment: Does it work by running your make command in Powershell or CMD?